# Laravel cronjob not executing properly on server

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduler

I made a cronjob which executes every day at **00:00**, it runs a **command** which I made in Laravel **`check:date`**.

**checkDate**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Programmefunding;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class checkDate extends Command{

protected $signature = 'check:date';

protected $description = 'Check if date is valid';


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    Programmefunding::where('date_end', '<', Carbon::now())
    ->where('status', 'open')
    ->update(['status' => 'closed']);
}
}
```

The command runs a query which checks for programme fundings which have the status 'open', checks their date and then proceeds to change their status to 'closed' if the 'date_end' value is less than today's date.

**When the cronjob executes I get this error**:

```
[ErrorException]


 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Does anyone know a solution?
**This is my command on the server:**

```
php /home/user/public_html/artisan check:date
```

**EDIT**

**Programmefunding model**

```
    <?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Programmefunding extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['status', 'name', 'description', 'permalink', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'why_end'];


    public static $enum_status = ["draft" => "Draft", "open" => "Opened", "closed" => "Closed", "announced" => "Announced", "deferred" => "Deferred"];



    /**
     * Set attribute to date format
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setDateStartAttribute($input)
    {
        if ($input != null && $input != '') {
            $this->attributes['date_start'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s', $input)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        } else {
            $this->attributes['date_start'] = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute from date format
     * @param $input
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDateStartAttribute($input)
    {
        $zeroDate = str_replace(['Y', 'm', 'd'], ['0000', '00', '00'], config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');

        if ($input != $zeroDate && $input != null) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input)->format(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }



    /**
     * Set attribute to date format
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setDateEndAttribute($input)
    {
        if ($input != null && $input != '') {
            $this->attributes['date_end'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s', $input)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        } else {
            $this->attributes['date_end'] = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute from date format
     * @param $input
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDateEndAttribute($input)
    {
        $zeroDate = str_replace(['Y', 'm', 'd'], ['0000', '00', '00'], config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');

        if ($input != $zeroDate && $input != null) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input)->format(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us `Programmefunding` model?

Comment: It's been added :) It's worth noting that 'php artisan check:date' works when run locally through cmd.

Comment: the table name on db is correct? doesn't print error line?

Comment: Yes everything is as it should be. I run the command on localhost using cmd and it works fine, but when it runs via cronjob i get the error.

Comment: Are you calling your script from crontab or Laravel Scheduler?

Comment: This might be completely unrelated to your command. Run it manually. See if the error persists. Then look into the logs, locate it, and eliminate it. I'm 99% sure it's a typo/error somewhere way outside the scope of your command.

Comment: From crontab. Running `php /home/user/public_html/artisan check:date` and `php /home/user/public_html/artisan schedule:run` give me the same results

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after a lot of digging.

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/user/public_html/artisan check:date
```

[Source.](http://blog.mauriziobonani.com/laravel-cron-jobs-on-shared-hosting/)

Thanks everyone for the help. :)